# How to click a button on a web page (name hidden) with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, buttonclick

My code is below.
It opens the browser, fills the form but I could not make it click the button. There is no button name or id in the source.

Thanks for the help.

Melis.

```
Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
    Sub ICON()
    Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
    Dim MyURL As String
    MyURL = "http://icon.icon-mng.com/login/"
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
    MyBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
    Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set htmlDoc = MyBrowser.document
    htmlDoc.all.login.Value = "xxx"
    htmlDoc.all.pass.Value = "xxx"
    For Each MyHTML_Element In htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If MyHTML_Element Like "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you submit the form insteading of trying to click the button.

```
  With MyBrowser
   .document.forms(0).submit 'your login form is indexed 0.
  End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS selector of:

```
button[class='float-right']
```

Which is `button` tag with attribute `class` with value of 'float-right'. The  "[]" 
 indicates attribute.

On your HTML:

[image: CSS Selector]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the css selector via the [`.selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of `document`.

```
.document.querySelector("button[class='float-right']").Click
```